# Cannot load configuration for Capistrano Receipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

The thing is that I want to get **parameters** for my Capistrano recipe from the console, so after looking on Google I came up with this:

```
task :set_repo do
  set :repository,  "git@github.com:#{configuration[:repo]}/MyApp.git"
  set :scm_user,  configuration[:repo]
end
```

When trying to run the task, I come up with a **"method missing"** error for the configuration hash. And after another search on Google I found that I have to load the configuration from Capistrano, so I added this code:

```
configuration = Capistrano::Configuration.respond_to?(:instance) ?
  Capistrano::Configuration.instance(true) :
  Capistrano.configuration(:must_exist)
```

But that's throwing a LoadError with the message **"Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe"**. I have tried requiring the capistrano/configuration module, but I keep getting the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a work around without using the configuration at all.

It seems that you can set a couple of tasks outside a namespace like this

```
desc "Use UserA's git repository"
task :usera do
  set :repository,  "git@github.com:UserA/MyApp.git"
  set :scm_user,  "UserA"
end

desc "Use UserB's git repository"
task :userb do
  set :repository,  "git@github.com:UserB/MyApp.git"
  set :scm_user,  "UserB"
end
```

and after doing this, you can simply call your deploy task prepending your repository task in the console. For example:

```
$ cap usera deploy
```

So this is going to call first your **usera** task and then your **deploy** task.

Answer (score 0):

You can set capistano variables from the command line.

For example, the below invocation would set the capistrano variable **scm_user** to 'userA' and the capistrano variable **repository** to  "http://myrepo.com/blah":

```
cap deploy -s scm_user="userA" -s repository="http://myrepo.com/blah"
```

This has the same effect as putting

```
set :scm_user, 'userA'
set :repository, 'http://myrepo.com/blah'
```

at the top of your deploy.rb file.